# Is it possible to evaluate $\lim_{x\to\frac12}\frac{4x^3-6x^2+1}{2x^3+7x^2-2}$ with other approaches?

Tags: calculus, limits

We have,$$\lim_{x\to\frac12}\frac{4x^3-6x^2+1}{2x^3+7x^2-2}$$
We can evaluate this limit by applying L'Hospital's Rule.

Another way is factoring  $2x-1$ in both numerator and denominator,
$$\require{cancel}\lim_{x\to\frac12}\frac{4x^3-6x^2+1}{2x^3+7x^2-2}=\lim_{x\to\frac12}\frac{\cancel{(2x-1)}(2x^2-2x-1)}{\cancel{(2x-1)}(x^2+4x+2)}=\frac{-6}{17}$$
Can we evaluate the limit with other approaches ?

Comment: Make $x=y+\frac 12$ to get $\frac{8 y^2-6}{4 y^2+20 y+17}$ and now $y\to 0$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Not a coincidence that your approach coincides with factoring out $(2x - 1)$.

Comment: You could first rewrite $\frac{4x^3-6x^2+1}{2x^3+7x^2-2}=2+\frac{-20x^2+5}{2x^3+7x^2-2}$, but that would not make a difference (and in fact would be more useful only for $x\to \infty$)

Comment: @user2661923. I did not want to factor. This is too tiring at my age ! (joke). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two methods you cite are not that different. In both cases, you eliminate the common root.

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{(x-a)P(x)}{(x-a)Q(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{((x-a)P(x))'}{((x-a)Q(x))'}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{P(x)+(x-a)P'(x)}{Q(x)+(x-a)Q'(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}.$$

Other attempts, such as translating the target argument to the origin are not essentially different.

You can also use a Taylor development of the numerator and denominator around $\dfrac12$ (limiting to the first order is enough), but this is again L'Hospital.

You can compute the gcd of the two polynomials by the Euclidean algorithm, and as a byproduct get the simplified fraction, but this is nothing really new.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why these 2 aren't good enough. You could try expanding into Taylor series around a nearby point, say $0$ or $1$, and then evaluating at $1/2$.

Comment: This computation seems terrible.